# matplotlib save animation in gif error

Tags: animation, matplotlib, gif

I want to save matplotlib animation in gif format.

I succeded to save animation to mp4 format, using code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

~some codes~

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw, update, interval=10, blit=False)
mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=60)
ani.save('myanimation.mp4',writer=mywriter)
```

but if I change myanimation.mp4 to gif format, python makes error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\edison\Edison_v4_backup_1\ver5.py", line 164, in <module>
    ani.save('demoanimation.gif',writer=mywriter);
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 718, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 204, in grab_frame
    dpi=self.dpi, **savefig_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 497, in print_raw
    renderer._renderer.write_rgba(filename_or_obj)
RuntimeError: Error writing to file
```

Seeing that I succeded to save in mp4 format, I don't know why it makes error when saving gif format.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because `matplotlib` does not support GIFs without external programs. If you have `imagemagick` correctly installed and configured, this should work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np


def init_animation():
    global line
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x))
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(2*np.pi*i / 50)*np.sin(x))
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init_animation, frames=50)
ani.save('/tmp/animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

[image]

Comment: This wokrs well. but can I reduce imagemagick file size? my program is just ~20kb but Imagemagick is about 60mb... I only need gif change feature in imagemagick. do you have any idea?

Comment: @user42298 I had a similar experience when animating a 3D plot. The axis and background grid were plotted and took most of the space. Removing these elements gave a nice and small animation. Out-of-the-box, gifs generated with ImageMagick have far better resolution than mp4s generated with ffmpeg. I hope this helps.

Comment: I get `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 513, in print_raw
    renderer._renderer.write_rgba(filename_or_obj)

RuntimeError: Error writing to file` running this script in Windows 7

Comment: is it possible to do this using more than one core? I am saving hundreds of videos.

Answer (score 7):

Just a reminder, before you use [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert images or videos to gif, **you need to modify Matplotlib's config and add ImageMagick's path**.

The following code will show you the config file path of Matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

For me the path is

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc
```

Then changing `animation.convert_path`

```
#animation.convert_path: 'convert' # Path to ImageMagick's convert binary.
                                   # On Windows use the full path since convert
                                   # is also the name of a system tool.
```

by adding **convert.exe** path to it

```
animation.convert_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe
```

Don't forget to remove the `#` before `animation.convert_path`.

After the above modification, Matplotlib and ImageMagick will perfectly work and output the `gif` file you want.

[image: example gif]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Used it on Mac OS X, except for the convert.exe ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate @SandervandenOord. I can't get this going with my Mac. Did you just drop the `convert.exe`. As such, `animation.convert_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16-HDRI`

Comment: @jonboy This was 3+ years ago, so I don't know exactly anymore. But a .exe is a windows file, so I guess yes that part should be left out.

Comment: @jonboy You can also still try my answer I gave below, which has 0 upvotes ;)

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a go to no avail. I was wondering if I was missing something else.

Answer (score 3):

Still had some trouble on Mac OS X, but the answers above pointed me in the right direction.

What I did came down to:

1. brew install imagemagick
2. edit the path file on location /etc/path (sudo vim path) and added the location of bin folder of imagemagick, in my case: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.6-4/bin
3. changed the settings of matplotlibrc as described above. You can find the location of matplotlibrc by doing in Python: `import matplotlib` `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`
   The settings you need to adjust can be found at the end of the file. I adjusted the following ones (commented out). Please note that those settings are not in 'quotes':

   animation.writer : imagemagick

   animation.codec : mpeg4

   animation.bitrate: -1

   animation.frame_format: png

   animation.convert_path: convert

Answer (score 2):

DrV's script didn't work for me on Windows 7, even though `convert` and `ffmpeg` both are in the system path.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 513, in print_raw
    renderer._renderer.write_rgba(filename_or_obj)

RuntimeError: Error writing to file
```

```
C:\Users>ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
   ...
```

```
C:\Users>convert
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-1 Q16 x64 2015-03-20 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
   ...
```

Editing my `matplotlibrc` to [add the full path to the exe](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Couldn-t-save-animation-as-gif-td42260.html#d1381733620000-747) fixed it:

```
###ANIMATION settings
#animation.html : 'none'           # How to display the animation as HTML in
                                   # the IPython notebook. 'html5' uses
                                   # HTML5 video tag.
#animation.writer : ffmpeg         # MovieWriter 'backend' to use
#animation.codec : mpeg4           # Codec to use for writing movie
#animation.bitrate: -1             # Controls size/quality tradeoff for movie.
                                   # -1 implies let utility auto-determine
#animation.frame_format: 'png'     # Controls frame format used by temp files
animation.ffmpeg_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\ffmpeg.exe   # Path to ffmpeg binary. Without full path
                                   # $PATH is searched
#animation.ffmpeg_args: ''         # Additional arguments to pass to ffmpeg
#animation.avconv_path: 'avconv'   # Path to avconv binary. Without full path
                                   # $PATH is searched
#animation.avconv_args: ''         # Additional arguments to pass to avconv
#animation.mencoder_path: 'mencoder'
                                   # Path to mencoder binary. Without full path
                                   # $PATH is searched
#animation.mencoder_args: ''       # Additional arguments to pass to mencoder
animation.convert_path: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\convert.exe # Path to ImageMagick's convert binary.
                                   # On Windows use the full path since convert
                                   # is also the name of a system tool.
```

[image: animated GIF output]

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried to install ffmpeg, didn't help. Then I tried to install imagemagick - failed. So I resorted to looping animation and recording it with screen **scraper** . I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it on Windows, without any hassle with Imagemagic or any other fancy libraries is to just use Pillowwriter, like so:

```
writer = animation.PillowWriter(fps=60)
ani.save('rotation.gif',writer=writer)
```