# matplotlib while loop (matplotlib.animation?)

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting data with matplotlib.

I would like to watch the data being plotted over a few seconds time.

Current script (below) is close.. It closes the existing plot and makes a new plot including one additional data point for each while loop iteration.

If the "fig=" and "ax1=" statements are instead typed above the loop, I get only a blank plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import time
#import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate2(i):

    k=1

    #fig=plt.figure()
    #ax1=fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    while k <=len(i):

        fig=plt.figure()
        ax1=fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        ax1.clear
        ax1.plot(i[0:k, 0], i[0:k, 1])

        plt.show()
        time.sleep(1)
        k=k+1
```

Here the a sample np array I've used:

```
test_data=np.array([[3, 7],[1, 2],[8, 11],[5, -12],[20, 25], [-3, 30], [2,2], [17, 17]])

animate2(test_data)
```

Also, if you think matplotlib.animation would work better, please provide an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `matplot.animation`. It uses `interval=miliseconds` instead of  `time.sleep()`. `repeat` stops looping. `frames` can be integer (number of frames) or list with numbers - every element from list is send to function as argument `i`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate2(i):

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(test_data[0:i, 0], test_data[0:i, 1])

# ---

test_data=np.array([[3, 7],[1, 2],[8, 11],[5, -12],[20, 25], [-3, 30], [2,2], [17, 17]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# create animation
animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=range(1, len(test_data)), interval=1000, repeat=False)

# start animation
plt.show()
```

---

You can also use `fargs=tuplet-with-arguments` to send own arguments to function

```
def animate2(i, data):

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(data[0:i, 0], data[0:i, 1])

# ---

animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=range(1, len(test_data)), 
                         fargs=(test_data, ), interval=1000)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I used this code to generate animated GIF

(it needs `imagemagick` installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25143651/1832058)

```
# create animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, frames=range(1, len(test_data)), interval=1000, repeat=False)

# save animation
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=1)
```

and got this result

[image]

Comment: cool @furas , thanks for the help!  Did you test this out? On my end, it still generates a blank, white plot..

Comment: My python environment is whatever comes with Enthought Canopy package, if that makes any difference

Comment: I tested this code. Maybe you get some error message and  his is why you don't get anything.

Comment: btw you can put `print()` in `animate2` and other places to see which part is executed and which not.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I have been testing things in jupyter notebook but don't see any error. I will continue trying.. thanks very much for your help

Comment: see image in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126915/discussion-between-user80112-and-furas).

Comment: got it! THANK YOU!! :D