# My animation is not graphing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, jupyter-notebook

> The problem

I need the animation to go fluid, but it is ploting frame by frame. The code is running in Jupyter Notebook.

> Here are the libraries

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal as sp
```

> Creating the functions to convolve

```
t_ini=0
t_final = 11
dt=0.1
t = np.arange(t_ini,t_final,dt)
expo = np.exp(-t)*np.piecewise(t,t>=0,[1,0])
t1 = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
s = np.sin(t1)
conv_=sp.convolve(s,expo,'full')
n_conv=np.arange(min(t1)+min(t),max(t1)+max(t)+0.1,0.1)
y = [0] * len(conv_)
t2 = [0] * len(n_conv)
```

> Here is the plotting

```
i = 0
for x in n_conv:

    y[i] = conv_[i]
    plt.cla()
    t2[i] = n_conv[i]
    plt.plot(t2,y)
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.5)

    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib` provides for instance `ArtistAnimation` that allows a seamless animation of precalculated graphs. I just added a couple of lines to your code. Only thing I changed was to use `enumerate` to improve your code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal as sp
import matplotlib.animation as anim

t_ini=0
t_final = 11
dt=0.1
t = np.arange(t_ini,t_final,dt)
expo = np.exp(-t)*np.piecewise(t,t>=0,[1,0])
t1 = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
s = np.sin(t1)
conv_=sp.convolve(s,expo,'full')
n_conv=np.arange(min(t1)+min(t),max(t1)+max(t)+0.1,0.1)
y = [0] * len(conv_)
t2 = [0] * len(n_conv)

#prepare figure for display
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

#create list to collect graphs for animation
img = []
for i, x in enumerate(n_conv):

    y[i] = conv_[i]
    t2[i] = n_conv[i]
    #append new graphs to  list
    newpic, = ax.plot(t2, y, c= "blue")
    img.append([newpic])

#animate the list of precalculated graphs
ani = anim.ArtistAnimation(fig, img, interval = 50)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: something is wrong in there it just give me a blank graph

Comment: Hm. I just pasted this code in my IDE and it animates the curve. What is your matplotlib version and your backend?

Comment: my matplotlib version is 2.0.0 what do you mean by my backend?

Comment: Ok when i run it from the cli in a .py file it animates the curve fine but in jupyter notebook it doesnt work. Why this could happen?

Comment: I don't use jupyter notebook, but seemingly some backends don't support animations, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878531/8881141 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43447370/8881141