# Is there Matplotlib FuncAnimation not work now?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook

I currently try to use matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation to create Dynamic candlestick, but when I Use the example code like this [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html#funcanimation).

My python version is 3.7.1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

But as images, I get an empty figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dZL8.png)

I don't know what's happened.

So I come to here ask your help.

All you guys responses are very helpful to me, It means a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: Plots in Jupyter are of the `png` format. So it won't be animated. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445103/inline-animations-in-jupyter). Your code runs fine in a Python interpreter terminal.

Comment: @funie200 it's kind of strange, I remember that I used to plot gif in jupyter notebook, I think there something wrong in my brain, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reasons that I can run Animation in jupyter-notebook before.

I use the interact function which in ipywidgets module.

And this function need to use an interactive backend; `%matplotlib notebook`

Somehow I open my old Animation code and `%matplotlib notebook` is missing.

So I can't run my Animation.

It will be like this result in images.

[image]

Again, thanks StackOverflow a lot.