# Seaborn scatter plot animation over datetime values

Tags: python, pandas, animation, seaborn

I thought this would turn out easy, but I am struggling now for a few hours to animate my seaborn scatter plots iterating over my datetime values.

The x and y variables are coordinates, and I would like to animate them according to the datetime variable, colored by their "id".

My data set looks like this:

```
df.head(10)
Out[64]: 
                     date    id    x    y  
0 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3479  353  118  
1 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3477  315   92  
2 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3473  351  176     
3 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3476  318  176     
4 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3386  148  255     
5 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3390  146  118     
6 2019-10-09 15:20:01.418  3447  469  167     
7 2019-10-09 15:20:03.898  3476  318  178     
8 2019-10-09 15:20:03.898  3479  357  117     
9 2019-10-09 15:20:03.898  3386  144  257
```

The plot that should be iterated looks like this:

[image].

Comment: Have you tried `matplotlib.animation`? There are two explainations:
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/
https://salernoali.medium.com/making-an-animated-graph-with-matplotlib-seaborn-3f865fa8c16a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a quick example. You might want to fix the axes limits to make the transitions nicer.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.animation 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def animate(date):
    df2 = df.query('date == @date')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.clear()
    return sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x='x', y='y', hue='id', ax=ax)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=df.date.unique(), interval=100, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

NB. I assumed that date is sorted in the order of the frames

edit: If using a Jupyter notebook, you should wrap the animation to display it. See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445103/inline-animations-in-jupyter).

```
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

xmin, xmax = df.x.agg(['min', 'max'])
ymin, ymax = df.y.agg(['min', 'max'])

def animate(date):
    df2 = df.query('date == @date')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.clear() # needed only to keep the points of the current frame
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
    return sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x='x', y='y', hue='id', ax=ax)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=df.date.unique(), interval=100, repeat=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: Thank you so much mozway, but is it possible my plots are blank after running this? Could you cross-check?

Comment: Are you running the code in a shell / as a script?

Comment: I use Spyder, its needed to use jupyter? - is it maybe possible to directly safe the animation to avoid a browser solution?

Comment: If you use Jupyter, you should wrap your animation for it to display, see my edit above.