# Particle in a Box not moving

Tags: python, matplotlib, oop, jupyter-notebook, particles

I'm currently trying to create a 2d Box with one particle inside, which moves with a certain velocity and "bounces off" at the walls. I'm using python and Matplotlib. Everytime I try to execute my code in Jupyter Notebook, it prints the 2d box with the particle inside, but it is not moving in any direction.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
point,= ax.plot(0,1, marker = 'o')

class particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.uniform(-1, 1)
        self.y = random.uniform(-1, 1)
        self.vx = np.random.random_sample()/5
        self.vy = np.random.random_sample()/5

    def movement(self):
        if self.x < -1 or self.x >= 1:
            self.vx *= -1
        if self.y < -1 or self.y >= 1:
            self.vy *= -1
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y +=self.vy

p = particle()
def update(frame):
    p.movement()
    
    point.set_data([p.x], [p.y])
    return point,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames = 100, interval = 5, blit = True)
plt.show
```

Comment: `plt.show` is a function, so you have to call it with `plt.show()`. I have a hard time believing ChatGPT didn't catch that typo for you - I saw it immediately and when I asked ChatGPT, it also pointed it out straightaway. On top of that, any IDE or editor for Python worth its salt will highlight that line of code and tell you (I use PyCharm, and it did). Do keep in mind that when running from something like PyCharm, it may not do great with the animation unless you run the script with the appropriate parameters, or just from the command line. (code works as expected, once you call `show()`)

Comment: Since OP is using Jupyter notebook, the `show()` is automatic so it should not make a difference that it was not explicitly called.  There is an existing question here about getting animations to work in Jupyter notebooks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445103/inline-animations-in-jupyter

Comment: Your current code block works just fine. You can see it working in your browser by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#animated_matplotlib-binder), clicking `launch binder` and letting the session start up. In the notebook that comes up, press the `plus` sign and then in the new cell, enter `%matplotlib notebook` as the first line and then paste in your code block below it. Run that cell and you'll see it working. (`plt.show` at the bottom won't interfere.) So now you know it works, so what is going on when you run it?

Comment: <continued> I sent you to use an older Jupyter Notebook and add the setting of the backend using `%matplotlib notebook` as the first line. So because everything is set up, it works! To be honest with the recent changes in the Jupyter tech,  the use of `FuncAnimation()` with matplotlib can be tricky to get working in an environment. You don't say anything about your interface and versions and so hard to provide specifics. For example, I think last I knew you needed `ipympl` for using this in JupyterLab, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example). ...

Comment: <continued>  (I'm not 100% sure on that last statement and I'd have to test more.) And although you say you are using Jupyter Notebook, it sometimes gets confusing if people are running something in an `.ipynb` file which is a Jupyter Notebook but actually using JupyterLab.  For the reasons that is hard to get the environment just right to do these sorts of `FuncAnimation()` animations, sometimes it is useful to develop where you know things work in the interface they work in, like the temporary one on a remote machine served via MyBinder that I point you at.

Comment: By default, the output in jupyter notebooks is not interactive. You need to add `%matplotlib widget` at the top of your cell to make them interactive. I tried this with your example and it worked. Here is an article that describes using `%matplotlib widget` directive - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-jupyterlab-inline-interactive-plots/

Comment: At Grasshopper, the OP will need to install `ipympl` for that to work as I alluded to in my comments already. The documentation of the [Basic Example](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example) I pointed at states `%matplotlib ipympl` and `%matplotlib` are now equivalent: "To activate the ipympl backend all you need to do is include the %matplotlib ipympl magic in the notebook. Alternatively you can use %matplotlib widget which will have the same effect."