# Saving Animated Matplotlib Chart to GIF

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I have an animated matplotlib chart that I'm trying to save to a .gif file, but I can't get my image writer to work.

I've installed imagemagick and verified that it works on my computer via the instructions given on its [installation page](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php), but when I do this:

```
anim.save('gd.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

I get the following error message:

```
MovieWriter imagemagick unavailable. Trying to use pillow instead.
```

However, doing `anim.save('gd.gif', writer='pillow')` gives the following error message:

```
ValueError: not enough image data
```

I tried installing ffmpeg with the command `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`. It looked like it installed correctly, but I don't know how to bind it to matplotlib apparently.

Specifying the writer as ffmpeg gives the same error message that I encountered with imagemagick.

I also tried adding imagemagick's path to matplotlib's config file path with the following line:

```
animation.convert_path: 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe'
```

That was [suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140952/matplotlib-save-animation-in-gif-error).

None of these seemed to have worked though.

I'm on Windows 10, and am using Python 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pinched this code from the interweb, which initially didn't work.
I changed the line:

```
rcParams['animation.convert_path'] = r'/usr/bin/convert'
```

to point to my `convert` binary and it fired up.
Admittedly, this is on Linux but I don't see that it should differ.
As noted by Mark Setchell in his comment to the original question, it appears that the name of the `binary` may well depend on the version/operating system that you are using. To isolate which one to use, I'd suggest trying the command on the `command line` first.
e.g. For me on Linux:

```
convert -version
```

gives:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Your mileage may vary! Especially as I can no longer remember much about issuing terminal commands on a Windows OS.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import rcParams

# configure full path for ImageMagick
rcParams['animation.convert_path'] = r'/usr/bin/convert'

TWOPI = 2*np.pi

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.001)
s = np.sin(t)
l = plt.plot(t, s)

ax = plt.axis([0,TWOPI,-1,1])

redDot, = plt.plot([0], [np.sin(0)], 'ro')

def animate(i):
    redDot.set_data(i, np.sin(i))
    return redDot,

# create animation using the animate() function with no repeat
myAnimation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(0.0, TWOPI, 0.1), \
                                      interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)

# save animation at 30 frames per second
myAnimation.save('myAnimation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, but I had to set the path to the magick.exe file, not convert.  Might be a good idea to note it as such in your answer.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel I have added a caveat. I don't know if you have the ability to edit the answer but if you do perhaps you could add your two cents worth above, where I start babbling. If not, stick it in a comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solve is to simply add `plt.show()` before running `anim.save('gd.gif', writer='imagemagick')`. When you close the plot it will save the animation correctly.